# Is it possible to select a different color for one candlestick?

Tags: colors, highcharts, candlestick-chart

Usually what you get with candlesticks bars two differentiating colors: blue and white or red and green in pairs etc...However, what i would like to know is if it is possible to highlight one of the candlestick bars within the chart with a third color? Let say the chart has a selection color pair blue and white and I would like to color the last candlestick in this chart Red. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add point as object and define color.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/GYduE/

```
{
                x: 1147910400000,
                open: 65.68,
                close: 66.26,
                low: 63.12,
                high: 63.1,
                color: 'red'
            }
```